# Elasticsearch build a query for products with filter and wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

We are switching from hibernate search (lucene) to elasticsearch. All products are stored in elasticsearch with the following fields:

```
name,description,articleNr, ean, herstellerNr, hersteller, price
```

lets assume we have to following products stored: (for example only: name, price, articleNr)

```
Rückenschild Karton kurz/br ws 10St für Ordner 1010 2.08 2572373
Ordner 101050, PP A4 RB 80mm grau 180° Ordner Präzisionsmechanik 3.39 2572374
Ordner 101050, PP A4 RB 80mm hellblau 180° Ordner Präzisionsmechanik 3.39 2572375
Ordner 101050, PP A4 RB 80mm hellgrün 180° Ordner Präzisionsmechanik 3.39 2572376
Ordner 101050, PP A4 RB 80mm hellrot 180° Ordner Präzisionsmechanik 3.39
HERMA Special - Papier - matt - permanent selbstklebend - beschichtet - weiß - 61 x 297 mm - 90 g/m² - 75 Etikett(en) (25 Bogen x 3) 8.68 2559675
HERMA Special - Papier - matt - permanent selbstklebend - beschichtet - weiß - 38 x 297 mm - 90 g/m² - 125 Etikett(en) (25 Bogen x 5) 8.68 2568156
Ablageschachtel 15cm, grau. Zur Langzeitlagerung von Hängemappen, 1.62 2568157
Ablageschachtel 20cm, grau. Zur Langzeitlagerung von Hängemappen, 1.93 2627350
OrdnerA4 8cm Pure Glam 2.64 2582799
agipa Ordnerrücken-Etiketten, kurz/ breit, weiß (66000322) 0.79
```

further, we can add filters but this seems to work already. So keep focus on the text search:
now the user type into the search the following phrase:

```
ordner 1010 rot
```

The query i wrote is:

```
                String _ja = "{" + 
                    "    'query': {" + 
                    "        'bool': {" + 
                    "            'must': {" + 
                    "                'multi_match': {" + 
                    "                    'query': '" + safe_input + "'," + 
                    "                    'fields': [" + 
                    "                        'name','artikelNr','ean','description','herstellerNr','hersteller'" +
                    "                    ],'type': 'phrase_prefix', 'tie_breaker': 0.3" + 
                    "                }" + 
                    "            }";
                    if(filter_ids != null) {
                    _ja +="        ,'filter': {";   
                        for(long id : filter_ids) {
                            _ja +="   'term': {" + 
                        "                    'filter': '" + id + "'" + 
                        "                }";
                        }
                        _ja +="            }";  
                    };

                    _ja += "}" + 
                    "    },\n";
                    if(sortby == 1) 
                        _ja += "'sort' : { 'pv_vk_netto': {'order': 'asc'} }";
                    else if(sortby == 2)
                        _ja += "'sort' : { 'pv_vk_netto': {'order': 'desc'} }";
                    else if(sortby == 3)
                        _ja += "'sort' : { 'name': {'order': 'asc'} }";
                    else if(sortby == 4)
                        _ja += "'sort' : { 'name': {'order': 'desc'} }";
                    else
                        _ja += "'sort' : { '_score': {'order': 'desc'} }";                  
                    _ja += "}";
                    _ja = _ja.replaceAll("'", "\"");
```

The query above is working for the search phrase:

```
order 1010
```

but if we type into the search

```
ordner 1010 rot
```

we do not get any results. I guess iam doing something wrong or i´m using the wrong query... :)

In my mind, every token in the search phrase, should be a wildcard token. 
So that the query sounds like search for products where in any field the token 
 *ordner* exists, and *1010* exists and *rot* exists.

Which results i expect:

```
Ordner 101050, PP A4 RB 80mm hellrot 180° Ordner Präzisionsmechanik 3.39
```

on the first place in the result list. What i need to change? many many thanks!

Comment: May you please provide the mapping of your index? It is important to understand how Elasticsearch analyzes the data for indexing. And maybe a couple of documents as they are, in JSON format so I could try to replicate the issue locally. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, all fields i need to focus on are from type 'text'. I have more fields stored in ES like 'pv_vk_netto, visible, out_of_sale' but these are not  neccesary for the search-query. The importent fields to search on are: product.name and product.desc. Most time a user ask for an product.name or a word inside the description of the product. So the query should be conform to search over multiple fields and every token should be handled as a wildcard-token. The reason is, sometimes a user do only know parts of the name :/ like: "copypaper 80g" but the product.name is: copypaper 80gramm. thx